# XMPP server : Account created but attributes not getting saved

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I am creating new user on *ejabberd* server.The user gets created. 
In the code below user 918 got created but no attribute were saved.

ejabberd server has access rule is :  `[register, [{allow,all}]]`

However, the attributes that i pass along with `createAccount()`, do not get saved on the *ejabberd* server.

libraries used - asmack-android-8-4.0.7, dnsjava-2.1.7.
XMPP server - ejabberd 2.1.11

Code is

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("myserver.co");
     config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
     conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
     conn1.connect();

     AccountManager accMan = AccountManager.getInstance(conn1);
     Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
     attributes.put("phone", "237");
     attributes.put("misc", "123");

     accMan.createAccount("918", "hellopass", attributes);

     conn1.login("918", "hellopass");
     accMan = AccountManager.getInstance(conn1);
     Log.d(TAG, "acc IMEI " + accMan.getAccountAttribute("misc")); // null returned here
    Log.d(TAG, "acc phone " + accMan.getAccountAttribute("phone")); // null returned here
```

The last 2 lines of code posted above, return null value.

I do not know what am i missing to correctly create account with attributes too getting saved.

thanks
Vilpesh.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are not stored on the account but on the Vcard. When you register a user, you can only pass username and password.
For the user information, you should look into setting your Vcard.